# Axios post response is html

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Good morning all,

i use: "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
"axios": "^0.19",
"vue": "^2.5.17",

I have a problem when I use a axios.put and route put my response.data is right (response.data: "ok") but in my axios.post and route post I receive an html in my response.data and I do not understand why someone can explain me please? and how to get an reponse.data:"ok" in my axios.post?

file .vue

```
let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('connexion', this.customer);
                formData.append('product', this.product);

                axios.post('hosting/', formData)
                    .then(response=> {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

file route

```
Route::post('hosting', ['uses' => 'Api\HostingController@cart']);
```

file controller

```
public function cart(Request $request)
{
    return 'ok';
}
```

my response when axios.post

[image: my response when post]

my response when axios.put

[image: my response when put]

thank's all for your help!

Comment: can you display the whole HTML ?

Comment: he just returns my main blade.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'Accept': 'application/json' in the request header field? and while returning the data use `return response()->json(/* your data here */)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] I have finally resolved this issue by just remove "/" on my url POST

The reason of the POST which sent me an html message is that in the POST if the "/" it waits for something params then while in PUT it removes the "/" automatically because no params behind!

```
axios.post('hosting', formData)
      .then(response=> {
              console.log(response);
            });
```

really a silly mistake sorry. I put the answer to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. Mine wasn't a route where I had to remove slash.
It was an actual API URL (Eg. **https://myapiurl.com/v1/upload**) to which I was making a **POST** request. My request was successful but I was getting HTML as a response data.

REASON:
I had my request URL as an environment variable and was referencing it.
So I was doing something like

```
const URL = process.env.MY_URL || "";
```

And for some reason, Axios was making a request to **URL=""** instead of the URL, and that was the reason I was getting HTML as the response data.

**So the revelation of this issue is that, check your request URL.**